# Remove one number at position n of the number in a string of numbers separated by slashes

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a character column with this configuration:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  codes = c("08001301001", "08002401002 / 08002601003 / 17134604034", "08004701005 / 08005101001"))
```

I want to remove the 6th digit of any number within the string. The numbers are always 10 characters long.

My code works. However I believe it might be done easier using RegEx, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
library(stringr)

remove_6_digit <- function(x){
  idxs <- str_locate_all(x,"/")[[1]][,1]
  
  for (idx in c(rev(idxs+7), 6)){
      str_sub(x, idx, idx) <- ""      
  }
  return(x)
}

result <- sapply(data$codes, remove_6_digit, USE.NAMES = F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("\\b(\\d{5})\\d", "\\1", data$codes)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hOYYFS/1). This will remove the 6th digit from the start of a digit sequence.

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\d{5})` - Capturing group 1 (`\1`): five digits
- `\d` - a digit.

While word boundary looks enough for the current scenario, a digit boundary is also an option in case the numbers are glued to word chars:

```r
gsub("(?<!\\d)(\\d{5})\\d", "\\1", data$codes, perl=TRUE)
```

where `perl=TRUE` enables the PCRE regex syntax and `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location.

And if you must only change *numeric* char sequences of 10 digits (no shorter and no longer) you can use

```r
gsub("\\b(\\d{5})\\d(\\d{4})\\b", "\\1\\2", data$codes)
gsub("(?<!\\d)(\\d{5})\\d(?=\\d{4}(?!\\d))", "\\1", data$codes, perl=TRUE)
```

One remark though: your numbers consist of 11 digits, so you need to replace `\\d{4}` with `\\d{5}`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hOYYFS/2).

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, using `stringr::str_replace_all` and lookaround :

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(codes = str_replace_all(codes, "(?<=\\d{5})\\d(?=\\d{5})", ""))

#>   id                                codes
#> 1  1                           0800101001
#> 2  2 0800201002 / 0800201003 / 1713404034
#> 3  3              0800401005 / 0800501001
```

Comment: More direct proposition : `data %>% mutate(codes = str_remove(codes, "(?<=\\d{5})\\d(?=.)")`

Comment: Thanks, @KévinLegueult, for having commented my solution! Your way is more direct indeed!

Comment: I wouldn't find this without your answer. Shorter version `data %>% mutate(codes = str_remove(codes, "(?<=.{5}).")`

Comment: Notice, @KévinLegueult, that, when there is more than one number (rows 2 and 3 of the dataframe), this your new solution seems not working well -- only one removal is operated.

Comment: And now that I went to check, I guess your previous solution does not work as well. You may want to use function `identical` to check whether the output of my solution or Wiktor Stribiżew's and the output of yours matches.